# background-image inside <section> won't display

Tags: css, layout, background-image

[This picture](http://postimg.org/image/nzs3x6y09/full/) inside my *section* tag (code below) won't display on the page. I wonder why...

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<title>Strona</title>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" screen="media,projection">
</head>
<body>
<section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
 width:100%;
 height:1230px;
}
body {
    width:90%
    height:100%;
}
section {
    width:100%;
    height:19.19%;
    background:url(header.jpg); *this path should work because the file is on my hard drive, this is not the issue of the path..
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Also I want my picture to scale proportionally (width and height) when I resize the browser window.

Comment: your missing semicolon on body width syntax error http://jsfiddle.net/8nL7omLb/

Comment: Ok, semicolon my bad but now I want my picture to scale proportionally (width and height) when I resize the browser window. but only width seems to scale down the height stays the same...which makes the picture disform. The IMG tag seems to be the answer but I do not want the IMG tag

Answer (score 0):

your missing semicolon on body width syntax error

```css
html {
    width:100%;
    height:1230px;
}
body {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
}
section {
    width:100%;
    height:19.19%;
    background-image:url("http://s12.postimg.org/xx34q95m3/header.jpg");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this HTML -**
some thing should be written in section and semicolon in body css also missing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head><title>Strona</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" screen="media,projection">
</head>
<body>
<section>Saurabh Singh Mehra</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
 width:100%;
 height:1230px;
}
body {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
}
section {
    width:100%;
    height:19.19%;
    background:url(header.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Ok, semicolon my bad but now I want my picture to scale proportionally (width and height) when I resize the browser window. but only width seems to scale down the height stays the same...which makes the picture disform. The IMG tag seems to be the answer but I do not want the IMG tag, I want background so that I can in tablet styles, mobile styles under that section substitute header.jpg picture for smaller size files

Comment: use height of image to auto

Comment: I just did change height of an image to auto and it works, it is a miracle, I thought that background property cannot be changed proportionally...